# How to reduce number of ticks in Axes3D object (in Matplotlib)

Tags: matplotlib

When I plot Axes3D object, the number of ticks on X/Y axes are somehow changing by themselves (for example, for 1x1 object, there are five ticks on each axes, while for 2x2 object, there are 7 ticks on each axes, see below screenshots)

3D plot for 1x1 object:
[image: 3D plot for 1x1 object]

3D plot for 2x2 object:
[image: 3D plot for 2x2 object]

The problem is that number of my tick-labels are lower than the number of ticks, therefore all tick-labels moved to the beginning of the axes.

So, how can I reduce/setup number of ticks?

Here is my code:

```
my_w = 2
my_h = 2        
x1_list_int = []    
x2_list_int = []   

y1_list_int = [[],[]] 
y1_list_int = [[0 for x in range(my_w)] for y in range(my_h)] #matrix initialization 

for i in xrange(my_w):
    print i
    x1_list_int.append(i*10)
    x2_list_int.append(i+1)            

for i in xrange(my_w):
    for j in xrange(my_h):         
        y1_list_int[i][j] = (i-3)*(j-2)+20

    data = np.array(y1_list_int)                        
    column_names = x2_list_int
    row_names = x1_list_int   

    fig = plt.figure()       
    ax = Axes3D(fig)


    lx= len(data[0])            # Work out matrix dimensions
    ly= len(data[:,0])         

    xpos = np.arange(0,lx,1)    # Set up a mesh of positions
    ypos = np.arange(0,ly,1)
    xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xpos+0.25, ypos+0.25)

    xpos = xpos.flatten()   # Convert positions to 1D array
    ypos = ypos.flatten()
    zpos = np.zeros(lx*ly)

    dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
    dy = dx.copy()           
    dz = data.flatten()

    ax.bar3d(xpos,ypos,zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='#00ceaa')

    ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(column_names)
    ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(row_names, rotation = 0)     

    label_x1 = 'X1'
    label_x2 = 'X2'
    label_y1 = 'Y1'

    ax.set_xlabel(label_x2)
    ax.set_ylabel(label_x1)
    ax.set_zlabel(label_y1)

    #-- save plot to the file
    plt.savefig(self.picture_file_path_1)
    ....
    plt.close() # final. data clean-up
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. Here it is:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
.....
ax.w_yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(len(x1_list_int)+1))
ax.w_xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(len(x2_list_int)+1))    
.....
```